# Moving and copying googlesheet to specific folder

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, drive

i am new to coding and google script. I am currently building a script that allows me to make a copy of a spreadsheet "car sales" and copy it to a newly created folder when a user registers on a google form. This folder is automatically created when the user submits his details on a google form. I have tried this code so far for copying the spreadsheet to the given folder but no success so far. I have tried this code so far and it is not working.

```
function getFolderByName(folderName) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("members"); //the google sheet which contains the new member name



//Pulling the name of the user's folder

var studentName = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(), 2).getValue(); 
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
var folderID = null;
      if (folders.hasNext())
       folderID = folders.next();
      return folderID;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far or did you search for similar topics?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, i have edited my questions with more clarifications and codes that i have used. can you please help me?

Comment: See [mcve]. *Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.*